# Counting the Number of Simple Paths in Undirected Graph

Tags: graph-theory, co.combinatorics, counting-complexity

How can I go about determining the number of unique simple paths within an undirected graph? Either for a certain length, or a range of acceptable lengths.

Recall that a simple path is a path with no cycles, so I'm talking about counting the number of paths with no cycle.

Comment: This has been asked already on mathoverflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18603/finding-all-paths-on-undirected-graph

Comment: Actually, the question at mathoverflow was about finding all paths, and not counting them. Finding them can be a lot harder.

Comment: Beside the references that are given in the answers, one trivial observation is that if one can count number of paths of length $n-1$ then can answer the question of existence of a hamiltonian path. So most likely it is not P.

Answer (score 21):

There are several algorithms that count the simple paths of length $k$ in $f(k)n^{k/2+O(1)}$ time, which is a whole lot better than brute force ($O(n^k)$ time). See e.g. [Vassilevska and Williams, 2009](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.156.345).

Answer (score 20):

It's #P-complete (Valiant, 1979) so you're unlikely to do a whole lot better than brute force, if you want the exact answer. Approximations are discussed by Roberts and Kroese (2007).

---

B. Roberts and D. P. Kroese, "[Estimating the number of $s$--$t$ paths in a graph](http://jgaa.info/accepted/2007/RobertsKroese2007.11.1.pdf)". *Journal of Graph Algorithms and Applications*, 11(1):195-214, 2007.

L. G. Valiant, "[The complexity of enumeration and reliability problems](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0208032)". *SIAM Journal on Computing* 8(3):410-421, 1979.

Comment: The Roberts and Kroese paper does not seem to give approximation guarantees. Is there a PTAS known for this problem?

Comment: @SashoNikolov, it seems unlikely that there is any reasonable approximation algorithm.  Given $G=(V,E)$ obtain $G'$ from $G$ by replacing each node by a clique of size $N=n^c$ where $n=|V|$ and $c\gg 1$.  For each simple path of length $\ell$ in $G$ there are roughly $(N!)^\ell$ paths in $G'$.  So if $G$ has an $s-t$ Hamiltonian path, there will be at least $(N!)^{n}$ or so simple $s-t$ paths in $G'$, and otherwise at most something like $(n-1)!(N!)^{n-1}$ simple $s-t$ paths.  So it should be hard to approximate within a factor of about $N!/(n-1)! \gg n^{c-1}!$.

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to add another approximation algorithm, a parametrized one:
For a fixed $\delta>0$ (or more preciesly, $\delta =\Omega(\frac{1}{poly(k)})$ ),  [you can compute](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=918B7428BAD06428C58DFF7CEF62BEBE?doi=10.1.1.146.408&rep=rep1&type=pdf) a $(1+\delta)$-approximation of the number of simple paths, in either undirected or directed graph, of length $k$ in time $O^*(2^{O(k)})$.