# The complexity of counting simple paths in a directed graph

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, counting-complexity

Let $G$ be a digraph (not necessarily a DAG) and let $s,t \in V(G)$. What is the complexity of counting the number of *simple* $s-t$ paths in $G$.

I would expect the problem to be #${\mathsf P}$-complete but have not been able to locate an exact reference.

Also notice that a number of similar questions have been answered correctly here
and elsewhere but not this precise question - to emphasise I am not interested in counting walks and/or undirected graphs (in the first case the variant is in ${\mathsf P}$ and in the other #${\mathsf P}$-hard).

Comment: The #P-completeness applies even for [undirected graphs](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20246/counting-the-number-of-simple-paths-in-undirected-graph), and this was discussed before. Perhaps a more interesting question would be if this is known to be $APX$-hard.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The #P-completeness proof of counting simple s-t paths in both undirected and directed graphs can be found in:

Leslie G. Valiant: [The Complexity of Enumeration and Reliability Problems](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/0208032). SIAM J. Comput. 8(3): 410-421 (1979)

From the paper:

...
**4. Some #P-complete problems**
...
14. S-T PATHS (i.e. SELF AVOIDING WALKS) (directed or undirected)
Input: $G; s,t \in V$
Output: Number of (directed) paths from $s$ to $t$ that visit every node at most once.
...